# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient' in .NET 6

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have developed a WPF app on .NET 5 (CRUD operations with Entity Framework Core). MSI packages are built with Wix toolset. Up to here everything works.

I am currently trying to convert the app to .NET 6. Everything runs perfectly, the Nuget packages can all be updated, building the MSI packages also works.

After installation on the client PC, the following message appears and the app crashes:

> Could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=2.0.20168.4, Culture=neutral, ..." The system cannot find the file specified.

Thanks for any help or ideas...

Comment: That seems a bit odd. Have you checked the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version referred in the dependencies? The latest version seems to be 4.1.0 and not 2.0.x

Comment: Ensure to install the correct version and verify it actually has been installed by checking the output window. You probably encountered an error during package installation.

Comment: I didn't commit the Runtimes folder and the files inside to the Wix project. So these files (and thus also Microsoft.Data.SqlClient) were missing after the installation.
That was the problem... WTF

Thanks for your answers!